# Get all @test (TestNg) methods in external program

Tags: java, reflection, testng

I have a UI (desktop app) which displays all the files with ".java" extension within a project/repository, so that a user can select these (Selected classes gets added to testng xml) and run them (desktop app runs testng xml).

My requirement is simple, I want to search for all the methods with @test annotation within a project/repository, instead of searching with file extension.

Can this be achieved by testng or java reflection ? Please suggest.

Any other suggestions/approaches are also welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Look at my open source library:
https://github.com/AutomatedOwl/testng-disabled-tests

```
private AtomicReference<String> extractJavaTestsCode(
            AtomicReference<String> javaTestsCode, IInvokedMethod iInvokedMethod) {

            // Search for files of java tests classes.
            try (Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(Paths.get(
                    System.getProperty("user.dir") + getTestsPath(iInvokedMethod)))) {
                paths.filter(Files::isRegularFile)

                        // For each java test file, concat its string.
                        .forEach(file -> {
                            String javaTestFileCode = readLinesFromFile(file.toString());
                            javaTestsCode.set(
                                    String.join("\n", javaTestsCode.get(), javaTestFileCode));
                        });
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                // Do nothing.
            }
        return javaTestsCode;
    }
```

It displays disabled tests methods in given path, with slight modifications to the regex parsing code it should do exactly what you describe.